# Threaten someone with something

Tags: sentence-meaning

> He threatened me with guys around.

In this sentence what confused me is that he threatened me with his guys or he threatened me and guys around. What does this sentence mean?

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

> He threatened me with guys around.

This sentence is a bit ambiguous as it stands.

As you say, it could either mean he got his guys to stand around you, and that was how he threatened you, *or* there were some random guys around when he threatened you (maybe verbally - they could be witnesses!)

> He threatened me by having his guys surround me.

Like this it's obvious that the way he threatened was to have his guys stand around you.

> He threatened me while his guys surrounded me.

Like this he made a double threat. A physical one of having his guys surround you and also making a verbal threat perhaps.

> He threatened me in front of some other guys.

Like this it's obvious they're not part of the threat, and merely bystanders.